# Wix CA.Dll file not be copied to correct folder

Tags: wix

I have a project that using customactions.  The customactions .ca.dll file is created when the project is built, which is all good.  However the folder that is is created in is not the one used by the installer.

All the other projects dlls are created in the installers folder, but the ca.dll file is not.

I guess this is expected given the .ca.dll is a special file, but I also assume there is a standard solution for this issue? I have googled unsuccessfully, so was hoping that someone may be able to supply links to the relevant documentation?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the output path for your custom action project needs to be changed.

Assuming you are using Visual Studio:

1. Right-click your custom action project in the Solution Explorer and click **Properties**.
2. Select **Build** from the left-hand menu.
3. Scroll down to the **Output** section and amend the **Output path** so that it is the same as (or equivalent to) the output path in your other projects.

Comment: The ca.dll goes to one of the correct locations, but it seems like it needs to also  be copied up the projects stack,


So Installer  references Project1

Project1 references Project2
Project2 (Custom Action) when built creates the customaction.CA.dll.  

When building the installer it fails as the ...ca.dll file is missing.  Which is true.  I'd have expected visual studio to have dealt with this ootb.

Comment: Could you add some more detail to the question, such as the relevant parts of your WiX files? Also, why does Project1 reference Project2 (the custom action project)? Typically your WiX project should reference your custom action project directly. Your WiX product file might include a `<Component>` element such as `<File Id="CustomActionAssembly" Source="$(var.CustomActionProject.TargetDir)$(var.CustomActionProject.TargetName).CA.dll" ... >` and a custom action element such as `<CustomAction Id='SchematiqSetupAction' FileKey='CustomActionAssembly' DllEntry ='MyCustomActionMethod' ... >`.